# How do I access this PHP array?

Tags: php

I have an array and if I write the code:

`echo $itemsub['addon_name_trans']`

then I get:

`Array`

and if I write the code:

`print_r($itemsub['addon_name_trans'])`

then I get

```
Array ( [sub_item_name_trans] => Array ( [1] => content ) )
```

How do I access this array so it just says `content`?

I tried 
`echo $itemsub['addon_name_trans']['sub_item_name_trans']` and `echo $itemsub['addon_name_trans']['0']` but neither worked.

Comment: `echo $itemsub['addon_name_trans']['sub_item_name_trans'][1];`

Comment: you're welcome.:):).